# Show actionbar while hiding navigation bar

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

What I want to do is to show action bar while hiding navigation bar.

My current code is like this

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);

ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

actionBar.setTitle("Title");
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

This is just the same as the one on official docs. This way can show action bar while hiding navigation bar and status bar. However, when I clicked the screen once, the layout changes when navigation bar and status bar appears.

So I tried to add `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION` and  `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE`. Layout doesn't collapse in this way. But this way doesn't show action bar on screen.

How can I do it?

Comment: you will need to add actionbar manually in onCreate method of activity.Paste your complete code to understand more briefly

Comment: @Pranita I think I already did. Please take a look.